# vertically align content and scroll box when reached the browser height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form that I want to be vertically centered and by clicking a link (**addAnother**) add an input to html each time and when reached the browser height scroll be applied to its container.
I'm using `display: table-cell` and `overflow-y: scroll` but then content is aligned in the middle.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-xl-6">
        <div id="spaceTeammatesBox" class="space-box form animated fadeInLeft">
            <div class="team-emails-outer">
                <div class="team-emails-inner">
                    <h3 class="mb-4">{% trans "Who is on your team?" %}</h3>
                    <div class="form-group forms">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control form-input" aria-describedby="email" autocomplete="off">
                        <span class="input-line" data-placeholder="Ex. name@example.com"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group forms">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control form-input" aria-describedby="email" autocomplete="off">
                        <span class="input-line" data-placeholder="Ex. name@example.com"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group forms">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control form-input" aria-describedby="email" autocomplete="off">
                        <span class="input-line" data-placeholder="Ex. name@example.com"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="add-teammate-link d-flex flex-row-reverse text-right">
                        <a href="#" id="addAnother">{% trans "add another" %}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in js I have:

```
$('#addAnother').click(function() {
        $('#spaceTeammatesBox').find('.form-group.forms').last().after(`
            <div class="form-group forms">
                <input type="email" class="form-control form-input" aria-describedby="email" autocomplete="off">
                <span class="input-line" data-placeholder="Ex. name@example.com"></span>
            </div>
        `);
    });
```

in the css:

```
#spaceTeammatesBox {
    background: lightblue;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.team-emails-outer {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}

.team-emails-inner {
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

How can I have vertical alignment and vertical scroll both at the same time in bootstrap 4?
Your help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you could use two containers: one for placing things vertically and another for the scroll. In your cace I would add to `<div class="team-emails-inner">` a new class `centered-content`. Then the content of this div I would wrap in another container with a class `scroll-box`. The css for the both classes looks like this:

```css
.centered-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* this vertically centers the child container */
}

.centered-content .scroll-box {
  max-height: 100%; /* this prevents the scroll-box to overflow the height of the parent */
  width: 100%; /* this pushes the scrollbar to the very edge of the box */
  overflow: auto; /* and this allows the scroll to appear only when necessary */
}
```

The whole thing works like this (open it in full page):

```js
$('#addAnother').click(function() {
  $('#spaceTeammatesBox').find('.form-group.forms').last().after(`
            <div class="form-group forms">
                <input type="email" class="form-control form-input" aria-describedby="email" autocomplete="off">
                <span class="input-line" data-placeholder="Ex. name@example.com"></span>
            </div>
        `);
});
```

```css
#spaceTeammatesBox {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}

.team-emails-inner {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  padding: 10px;
}

.centered-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.centered-content .scroll-box {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-xl-6">
    <div id="spaceTeammatesBox" class="space-box form animated fadeInLeft">
      <div class="team-emails-outer">
        <div class="team-emails-inner centered-content">
          <section class="scroll-box">
            <h3 class="mb-4">{% trans "Who is on your team?" %}</h3>
            <div class="form-group forms">
              <input type="email" class="form-control form-input" aria-describedby="email" autocomplete="off">
              <span class="input-line" data-placeholder="Ex. name@example.com"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group forms">
              <input type="email" class="form-control form-input" aria-describedby="email" autocomplete="off">
              <span class="input-line" data-placeholder="Ex. name@example.com"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group forms">
              <input type="email" class="form-control form-input" aria-describedby="email" autocomplete="off">
              <span class="input-line" data-placeholder="Ex. name@example.com"></span>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="add-teammate-link d-flex flex-row-reverse text-right">
            <a href="#" id="addAnother">{% trans "add another" %}</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```